# Where need to correct check User for dublicate email in database, use mvc webapp spring security, form home login logout

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-security

Security check user by email work correct. But i can add new User with dublicate email.And  password userEntity correct encrypt. 
Maybe need in UserService method before userRepository.save(user); insert check "if", so userRepository.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail); if i take "true" after catch exception with string "email dublicate" ? need to see like this message in regForm.jsp in browser

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a good approach is to for instance enforce unique email at the entity level.
[image: Email constraint and unique on User table]

Comment: and in browser page i have what? message, or ide die with hibernate exception...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions here is good but please post code etc in answers (also in questions) as text. Posing images may be useful in addition to text but images cannot be searched which makes useful pieces of code hard to find in Qs or As.